# How to compare two dates

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

```
public List<Object[]> Medicine(java.util.Date asd){
    String hql = "select u.date, from EsencijalnaLista where u.date > :s";
    Query query = HibernateUtil.getSession().createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("s", asd);
    return query.list();
}
```

This is a query and I want to compare 2 dates. One is selected and it is "asd". The second is in a database and it is compared.

Comment: (If my answer doesn't help, please say what happens when you try it, along with what happens when you try your current code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your HQL is just missing anything saying what `u` is. Try:

```
String hql = "select u.date from EsencijalnaLista as u where u.date > :s";
```